# How to scanf until I get something not of the same form

Tags: c, loops, scanf

I am inputting a text file from Stdin, which will have an undetermined number of coordinates, then a #, then another set of coordinates. How do I scanf the coordinates into a loop that stops once I hit the #, that will let me scanf the rest of the coordinates after the #?

I have tried a couple of loops like:

```
    `while(scanf("[%d,%d]\n", &x, &y) == 1){

        //do stuff//

}
```

but I dont feel like im getting any closer to an answer, any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers

input example (the # doesnt have "" around it but it disappears on here if it doenst):

```
[0,0]  
[1,1]  
[2,2]  
"#"  
[1,3]  
[3,6]  
[9,8]
```

Comment: Post a couple of example lines of input (indented by 4-spaces). There are several ways to accomplish this, but it will help to see the input.

Comment: You should be testing for 2, not 1.  Are the square brackets in the data?  If so, you’ll get zero back when the input is a #

Comment: Get rid of the `'\n'` in `"[%d,%d]\n"` -- it isn't doing what you think it is doing. Use `fgets` into a buffer and then `sscanf`. (otherwise you will need to read and discard characters until you read `'\n'` or `EOF`)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to wrap the code into fgets(or readline):.

```
    char buff[2048] ;
    while ( fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin )) {
        // Check of 'last' marker
        if ( buff[0] == '#' ) break ;
        // Check if looks like coordinates
        if ( sscanf(buff, "[%d,%d]\n", &x, &y) == 2 ) {
             // do something
        } ;
    } ;
```

- Minor fix to sscanf return code (2 instead of 1) - check for parsing of 2 fields

Comment: Next comment, what purpose does `'\n'` serve in `"[%d,%d]\n"`?

Answer (score 0):

Your input data delimited by a double-quoted `"#"` complicates matters slightly. Your attempt to read with `scanf` is destined to fail. Your `scanf` format string of `"[%d,%d]\n"` does not read/discard the `'\n'` at the end of the line. In fact it doesn't match a `'\n'` at all. `scanf` does not interpret control characters, so what the `'\n'` in your format string is looking for is a literal `'n'` leading to an *input-failure* after the two conversions take place.

You have two options:

1. remove the `'\n'` from your format string, continue with `scanf` (not recommended) and then manually read/discard all remaining characters in the line until a `'\n'` is reached (using either `getchar()` or `fgetc()`); or
2. read each line into a buffer using a *line-oriented* input function like `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` to ensure a complete line of data is read each time and then parse the information you need from the buffer with `sscanf` (preferred method).

Taking the preferred approach above, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC];     /* buffer for each line */
    int x, y, n = 0;    /* coordinates & counter */

    printf ("set[%d]:", n++);                   /* initial set[]: label */
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {          /* read each line */
        if (strncmp (buf, "\"#\"", 3) == 0)     /* line starts with "#"? */
            printf ("\nset[%d]:", n++);         /* output new set[]: label */
        else if (sscanf (buf, " [%d,%d]", &x, &y) == 2) /* 2 conversions? */
            printf (" %d,%d", x, y);            /* output coordinates */
    }
    putchar ('\n');     /* tidy up with newline */

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** if your file simply contained `#` instead of `"#"`, you could simply check the first character in the buffer instead of using `strncmp`)

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/coordgroups.txt
[0,0]
[1,1]
[2,2]
"#"
[1,3]
[3,6]
[9,8]
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readcoords < dat/coordgroups.txt
set[0]: 0,0 1,1 2,2
set[1]: 1,3 3,6 9,8
```

Look thing over and let me know if you have further questions.